# Evidence that girls/women feel pain greater than boys/men?

Tags: pain

I found this article that says males and females feel pain "differently", but doesn't suggest one necessarily feels "more" pain from the same impacted force/stimuli:
http://healthyliving.msn.com/health-wellness/do-women-have-a-higher-pain-threshold-1?pageart=2

Also, MythBusters performed the ice water hand hold test:
http://popwatch.ew.com/2010/04/23/mythbusters-confirms-whether-women-tolerate-pain-better-than-men/

However, there's debates on whether holding your hand longer in ice actually constitutes more pain threshold in its entirety, as environmental and hereditary factors can take place.

Many U.S. military sergeants, Marines, and others have debated that women do not have the capability to fight in a battle field and endure the effects of war as a man can, due to being too physically taxing and strenous on their bodies. However, in the U.S., females can join infantry; there's no longer a law against it, that is.

So, in conclusion, has it been verified in any way that men/women can feel more pain than men/women?

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/do-either-men-or-women-have-higher-pain-tolerance-than-the-other?rq=1

Comment: @user I'd call that a duplcate. I've also seen claims that women have slightly better pain tolerance except during the premenstral days of their cycle when they are *more* sensitive.